# Why are my flex children not equal sizes?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am re-writing my question after digging further and finding that this issue is only evident on some devices, suggesting it is related to viewport size.

As you can see in the code, the parent has a set height + width and the children should all have identical heights.

Yet as you can see in the picture below, a screenshot from my laptop, the code in the demo sometimes produces children of different sizes based on the size of the parent container and as I just mentioned, the device it's viewed on.

So how can I ensure they appear equal heights regardless of the device they are viewed on or/the size of the parent container?

[Bug-example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKuNE.png)

```js
console.clear();
```

```css
.header {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-container {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  transform: scale(5);
}

.child {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  height: 10%;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```

Comment: Flexbox does not guarantee this in general.  Try adding `flex: 1` to the `.child` class.  This sets `flex-shrink` and `flex-grow` to 1  and `flex-basis` to 0.  You can tweak these individually to your case if it helps

Comment: @possum Sorry, I missed some context in my original post that I have now added. I want 3 equal heighted divs in my container that are spaced evenly. However, through my implementation, one always appears to have greater height than the others. Hope this makes more sense :)

Comment: Please update the demo above to show the problem. It's not apparent.

Comment: @isherwood When i click play demo on my screen the middle div is noticeably bigger than the outer 2, is this not the case for you?

Comment: Don't tell _me_ down here. Tell the community in your question. Please take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

As you already choose to build the `flex-box` flow you may ignore the width of children elements - just leave them with full scale. Set only the height param. Also, for the parent container you may add some paddings and gaps - it'll play perfectly with the flex-box.
Down there is a sample with `TailwindCSS` (as I saw you already added it to your example), but you are free to transform it all into custom styles for your best practice.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="h-screen p-24 bg-slate-900 text-white">
  <!-- flex-container -->
  <div class="w-20 h-20 flex flex-col justify-center items-center gap-4 p-3 bg-slate-700">
    <!-- lines -->
    <div class="w-full h-4 bg-white"></div>
    <div class="w-full h-4 bg-white"></div>
    <div class="w-full h-4 bg-white"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```